# R package para converter números em texto por extenso do número

Tags: r

Estou procurando um pacote de R que converta um número no número escrito por extenso. A funcionalidade seria, por exemplo, `"134" = "cento e trinta e quatro"`.

Alguém conhece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que eu saiba, não existe nada pronto, mas como as regras são simples não é difícil de programar.

Você precisa de alguns de-paras:

```
excessoes <- data.frame(
  num = 11:19,
  nome = c("onze", "doze", "treze", "catorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezessete", "dezoito", "dezenove"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

unidades <- data.frame(
  num = 1:9,
  nome = c("um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis", "sete", "oito", "nove"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)  

dezenas <- data.frame(
  num = 1:9,
  nome = c("dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinquenta", "sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Em seguida de uma função que junte de acordo com as regras de numerais.

```
library(stringr)
escrever_numero <- function(x){

  tamanho <- str_length(x)
  num_vetor <- unlist(str_split(x, ""))

  if(x %in% excessoes$num){
    return(excessoes$nome[excessoes$num == x])
  } else {
    unidade <- num_vetor[tamanho]
    unidade <- unidades$nome[unidades$num == unidade]
    if(tamanho > 1){
      dezena <- num_vetor[tamanho -1]
      dezena <- dezenas$nome[dezenas$num == dezena]
    }
  }

  if(length(unidade) == 0){
    return(dezena)
  } else if (tamanho > 1){
    return(paste(dezena, "e", unidade))
  } else{
    paste(unidade)
  }

}
```

Fiz uma função rapidinho, que funciona p/ numeros de 1 a 99. Mas se você entender a lógica é fácil expandir para mais números.

```
> escrever_numero(81)
[1] "oitenta e um"
> escrever_numero(99)
[1] "noventa e nove"
> escrever_numero(1)
[1] "um"
> escrever_numero(10)
[1] "dez"
> escrever_numero(15)
[1] "quinze"
```

Não está muito elegante, mas pode ajudar...